# How to use rest web service in bpel?

Tags: bpel

I have a question about bpel oracle...
I want use .json in bpel so I have to use rest web service in expose bpel but when I send request in rest client the response have problem,I search about it then use nxsd but my problem don't solve...please help me
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using 'HTTP Binding' inside your Bpel process?

Create a partner link, specify REST service endpoint and choose request and response schema elements.

Add Invoke activity and link it to HTTP Binding adapter.